# Find all telephone numbers in a string by regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have to find all telephone numbers in a string.

I do it this way (my simplified c# testcode):

```
const string testString = "+39702937311";

        var m = new Regex("(?<telephonenumber>^\\+?(\\d[\\d-. ]+)?(\\([\\d-. ]+\\))?[\\d-. ]+\\d$)").Matches(testString);

        foreach (Match match in m)
        {
            var nr = match.Groups["telephonenumber"].Value;
            Debug.WriteLine(nr);

            foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Index={0}, Value={1}", capture.Index, capture.Value);
            }
        }
```

It works, when the string itself a telephone number. But if the string is a longer string that contains a telephone number, it does not find telephone numbers.

So, if I test by

```
const string testString = "Hello! This is a telephone number: +39702937311 You should call it";
```

it does not find +39702937311 as a telephone number.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<telephonenumber>^\\+?(\\d[\\d-. ]+)?(\\([\\d-. ]+\\))?[\\d-. ]+\\d$)
                   ^                                                 ^
```

The indicated symbols are line boundary matchers. if you want to math words with this, you need a word boundary matcher.

replace `^` and `$` with `\b` to indicate you want to match a word rather than a line.